How to resolve the below error : Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler. ParsedResource@3e55a5d0
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler. ParsedResource@3e55a5d0.
Showing error in values.xml file which is unedited file with two errors
Tried clear project caches and re-build, synced the gradle up to date but no luck

Please edit your question and describe in detail what you are trying to do, what command you execute that ends up in this error. Also please include the relevant parts of your code like Gradle config.
